# iOS remote control - disable next and previous song buttons

Tags: ios, iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, remote-control

I'm writing a streaming app that's using the remote control feature (remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:).

I can start and stop songs with the remote control as expected.

But I can't seem find out how to disable the next and previous song button on the home screen (double-tap home and swipe all the way to the left).

I'm using a MPMoviePlayerController internally.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know the API doesn't allow you to show the buttons as disabled. I think the best you can do is just not take any action when one of those buttons are pressed.

I have not observed any other major app that shows the remote buttons as disabled.

Comment: There is a solution to desable them: [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32994374/2597566)